# How to add a text box in a div with a value with jquery (edit in place)

Tags: jquery, ajax, edit-in-place

HI, I'm trying to add edit in place functionality to my site with jquery. I don't want to use a plugin, so my idea was that when you click the div that has the content in it, it would replace the div with a text box, then on blur it would submit a post to save the content.

So far I have the click event, but I'm not sure how to replace the div with a text box, and then make it submit on blur, I can probably figure out the ajax request though.

Any help would be great, thanks. So far this is what I have... just the click event:

```
$('.control-panel-profile-update').click(function() {
      alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely written, and it might not completely work, but it's worth a shot. Good luck:

```
$('.control-panel-profile-update').live('click', function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" id="inlineEdit" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />');

  $('#inlineEdit').focus().live('blur keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode && event.keyCode != 13) return false;

    $(this).replaceWith('<div class="control-panel-profile-update">' + $(this).val() + '</div>');
  });
});
```

---

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Af6X6/2/. I added support for the `enter` key too.

Comment: Blender... seems to be working, is there a way to take the value that's in the div and put it into the value of the text box that's generated?

Comment: Also, seems to not be clearing the text box on blur, I wouldnt mind if it was only submitted when they press enter, and when the text box was clicked away it woudld go back to the way it was

Comment: I like your implementation alot +1

Comment: It's less compact than yours, though, and it assigns an ID to the element, so that might be conflicting. +1 for `contenteditable`, though. I didn't even know about it!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this, in modern browsers you can use contenteditable=true, and then on blur send the new contents on their way. This takes care of having to swap out a textarea.

```
<div contenteditable="true">Some Text</div>
```

or you can do it the js way.

http://jsfiddle.net/2RyT2/23/

```
$(function(){
    $("#meText").live('click',function(){
        var originalDiv = this;
            $(this).replaceWith($("<textarea></textarea>").text($(this).text()).width($(this).width()).height($(this).height()).blur(function(){$(this).replaceWith($(originalDiv).text($(this).val()));}));
    });
});
```

Comment: You may want to look at blenders answer as well, his is a bit more elegant than mine. replaceWith is probably a better way to go.

Comment: Hmm thanks, yea his seems to make a little more sense. I'm getting lost with the whole that, this, text, etc.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer, blender gets some credit for the use of replaceWith() for sure.

Comment: I'd add a `.focus()`. It would confuse the user if they have to click and then click again to exit. But The textarea is a pretty good idea. Adding a `style="resize: none;"` would make it look a bit more inputy.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to add a hidden div with a textbox in it.

```
<div style="display:none; id="textbox_container">
<textarea id="box"></textarea>
</div>
```

Then in your click function, you show the textbox

```
$("#textbox_container").show();
```

You can update the value of the textbox with `.val("")`

Hope this helps.